# Will Dispose() be called if a .ctor() throws?

Tags: c#, constructor, exception, idisposable

I've got a class with one `IDisposable` member variable initialized in-line, and another `IDisposable` in the constructor.

Will `Dispose()` be called if the constructor throws?  If so, then I presume the `null` check is necessary...?  If not, then how does the in-line member get disposed?

```
    sealed class SomeDisposable : IDisposable { ... }

    sealed class Foo : IDisposable
    {
        readonly SomeDisposable sd1= new SomeDisposable(); // this doesn't throw
        readonly SomeDisposable sd2;
        public Foo()
        {
            sd2 = new SomeDisposable(); // assume this throws
            // how does sd1 get Dispose()d?
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            sd1.Dispose();
            if (sd2!= null) // is this null check necessary?
                sd2.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No.  Don't add it yourself either, a disaster happened.  You cannot reason out what's going to happen when you run code after that earth-quake dumped your process into the ocean.

Comment: There is just no point in disposing anything a microsecond before your program crashes to the desktop.  Do keep in mind that disposal is always optional.  If it causes *more* problems than it solves then you must strongly avoid using it.

Comment: It is because an earth-quake happened.  A C# statement can fail for many reasons, the vast majority are very, very nasty and you cannot assume that you can safely continue running code.  Like this kind of statement.  Never happens, but if it does happen then you never want to make it difficult to diagnose the reason.  You make it difficult by running code after the earth-quake.

Comment: You are not hearing me.  It is such a pervasive problem that Microsoft did something about it, they added the notion of "critical exceptions" to the CLR.  An earth-quake now unconditionally terminates your program without giving you a chance to catch the exception.  So go ahead, you can no longer shoot your leg off.   The code you add simply will never get used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you're using the following code in the form:

```
var foo = new Foo(someByteArray);
```

And your constructor throws an exception, then `foo` will be null, because the class constructor didn't complete. Any attempt to call it's `Dispose` will cause a NRE to occur.

Comment: The CLR doesn't call `Dispose` for you, unless you called it via a [*finalizer*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly. Your `outputStream` field, as it is private and not referenced from the outside, will be collected once your GC kicks in for a collection. Note `outStream` could be initialized as it's initialization runs prior to the class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is at present no way in C# to safely initialize an `IDisposable` with an in-line initializer except through a nasty hack involving `ThreadStatic` variables.  The constructor must be called via factory method that creates a disposal-manager object and stores a reference in a thread-static field.  Field initializers can then wrap their value in a call to a static method which will add them to the disposal-manager object.

The actual field-initializer syntax ends up being pretty reasonable:

```
DisposalManager Cleaner = DisposalManager.CurrentManager;
DType1 DField1 = DisposalManager.Guard(new DType1);
DType2 DField2 = DisposalManager.Guard(new DType2);
```

so does the `Dispose` cleanup:

```
void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  Cleaner.Cleanup(disposing);
}
```

Unfortunately, the needs to have every single call to `Guard` do its own access to the thread-static field, and to have all constructor calls wrapped in factory methods, makes the construct rather ugly.  Too bad, since being able to use a single line to declare, create, and clean up a field is much nicer than having to do those things at three separate places in the code.

Comment: @Dan: The only such code I've written was in VB.NET rather than C#, and used the semantics of VB.NET field initializers to avoid the need for thread-static variables.  I don't think there should be anything particularly difficult about it.  The biggest hassle is not writing the DisposalManager--it's dealing with all the factory methods.  Normally a factory method would call a constructor, but here it's necessary that a derived-class constructor get wrapped in a try/finally block within a base class factory, which means that one ends up needing two derived-class factories...

Comment: ...a public factory which then gives the base-class factory a delegate to the private derived-class factory, which then calls the derived class constructor which in turn chains to the base-class constructor.  I suspect it would be possible to use Reflection to auto-generate factory classes that chain to the proper code in the proper sequence with the proper protections, such that all the ugliness would be confined to a general-purpose factory-builder class, but I don't know how to do that.  Without that, I'm not sure the cleanliness of the resource declaration would justify the ugliness...

Comment: ...necessary to support it.  I suspect some people would feel the improvement in resource-declaration cleanliness justifies the cost elsewhere, but I don't know that I do.  What would be justified would be a means of having proper language/framework for such a thing, so that it would only have to be implemented once, in the language, rather than once in every class that wants such cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Tried this:

```
try
{
  //caller
  using (var x = new Disposable1()) { }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}


public class Disposable1 : IDisposable
{
    private Disposable2 first = new Disposable2();
    private Disposable2 second;

    public Disposable1()
    {
        second = new Disposable2("Goodbye!");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Disposable1.Dispose()");

        first.Dispose();
        if (second != null)
            second.Dispose();
    }
}

public class Disposable2 : IDisposable
{
    public string Whatever { get; set; }

    public Disposable2() { Whatever = "Hello!"; }
    public Disposable2(string whatever)
    {
        Whatever = whatever;
        throw new Exception("Doh!");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Disposable2.Dispose()" + Whatever);
    }
}
```

...and the output was...

```
Doh!
```

So it does appear that neither member is initialized or disposed.

Comment: That's because `Dispose` will run from within the  finally block after the exception occurs. But your code example doesn't resamble the code execution. He never manages to assign anything before the exception propogating.

Comment: This isn't really the same scenario. Your `Disposable1` is not throwing in its constructor.

Comment: The setup is actually identical. This line in the Disposable1 constructor causes an exception: *second = new Disposable2("Goodbye!");*. I'm just using custom classes instead of streams.

Comment: @Colin That isn't the constructor. No exception is actually going to be thrown in this code.

Comment: Daggnabbit! Typo in my program. "Dispose()" was meant to be be "Disposable1()". I updated the answer to reflect the real output.